# R or Python Equivalent to SAS Text Miner

Tags: text-mining

I am working on a project where a former member of the team used SAS Text Miner (https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/txtminer/14.1/tmref.pdf) to complete some text mining. Unfortunately, this member of the team has moved on and no one has access to the code they wrote to do the analysis. My job is to update the analysis with new data, but I only have two weeks to do it and I have never used SAS. I'm looking for an R or Python equivalent to SAS's Text Mining capabilities. From what I can tell, the former  colleague leveraged SAS's Parse, Filter, and Cluster nodes (page 6 of pdf). The deliverable should be a text concept linking diagram or table. Any ideas for good packages for this in R or python? Thanks.

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: That said, I'm sympathetic to your situation. You could ask on our chat ([ten fold](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold)), [SO]'s R chat room ([R Public](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public)), possibly a Python chat room there (I don't know which), or the r-help listserv.

Comment: @gung Are you implying this question should be moved to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Not really, asking for packages, eg, is off topic on [SO] I believe. But you could try the other places I listed.